# How to create a single file executable with celery tasks

Tags: python, django, celery, pyinstaller

I've successfully learned some basics of Celery, but I've found no simple way to create single file executable (with no need to run celerybeat as a separate process to run periodic tasks). It is possible to write an app and start its worker process (http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/3.1/userguide/application.html):

```
from datetime import timedelta
from celery import Celery
app = Celery()

@app.task
def test():
    print("he-he")

app.conf.update(
    BROKER_URL="redis://localhost:6379",
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND="redis://localhost:6379",
    CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT=["application/json"],
    CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER="json",
    CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER="json",
    CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE={
        'runs-every-30-seconds': {
            'task': '__main__.test',
            'schedule': timedelta(seconds=30),
        },
    }
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.worker_main()
```

But how can I start the beat process from the same module to start running periodic tasks (in order not to run celerybeat daemon as a separate executable)? It's important, because I'd like to use pyinstaller, so no dedicated Python interpreter will be available on client machines.

Answer (score 3):

One can run create simple beat process like that:

```
# that's the class to run the beat process
from celery.bin.beat import beat
# your app
from celery_tasks import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    beat(app=app).run()
```